# Smooth region boundary

Tags: plotting, export, regions

I have a 2D region that is defined by the union of a number of polygons (the list of the polygons is available [here](http://pastebin.com/azNJSbVg)).
I can easily visualize the region using

```
Region[RegionUnion @@ data]
```

In the given example, the region looks something like this:

[image]

However, if you evaluate

```
InputForm@Show@Region[RegionUnion @@ data]
```

you can see that the `Graphics` object is still made up of the individual polygons. Because of this, exporting the graphic as a PDF (in the real case, I have a diagram with many regions) generates a relatively large file, which I want to avoid.

Also, if you zoom in on the right end of the region, you can see some artefacts in the region boundary, that could be smoothed out.

I tried

```
Region[DiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion @@ data, MeshQualityGoal -> "Minimal"]]
```

without much success. Is there an easy way to get a simple expression (for example, points defining a single polygon) for a smooth region boundary in such a case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some reduction can be achieved by using `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[]` and careful extraction of the boundary points:

```
Import["http://pastebin.com/raw/azNJSbVg", "Package"];
bdr = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion @@ data];

pts = MeshCoordinates[bdr];
polys = Polygon[pts[[#]]] & /@ 
        Map[First, FindCycle[DirectedEdge @@@ (First /@ MeshCells[bdr, 1]), ∞, All], {2}];

{Length[data], Length[polys]}
   {57, 10}

Graphics[{Red, EdgeForm[White], polys}]
```

[image: some polygon]