# How to make BoundaryDiscretizeRegion work for a RegionUnion of polygons?

Tags: plotting, export, regions

This question is related to [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140809/smooth-region-boundary).
I want to display the `RegionUnion` of a large set of smaller polygons. If simply use `Region` or `RegionPlot`, the exported PDF becomes huge because each polygon is rendered individually.

The method in the answer of the [linked question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140809/smooth-region-boundary) helps, but for some reason `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` fails in some cases. For example, for [this data set](https://pastebin.com/sZkAeVGg), the kernel is at 100% for a while and nothing seems to happen if I use

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion @@ data]
```

I tried rescaling the data, but in this case the function `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` doesn't do anything at all:

```
data[[All, 1, All, 2]] = Rescale[data[[All, 1, All, 2]]];
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion @@ data]
```

Any ideas on how to make `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` work for such a case? Or another good way to display the region boundary?

Comment: I can't even get the first polygon to discretize `DiscretizeRegion@First@data` takes too long for my patience.